# mysql group by value in multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

```
    code1 | code2 | code3 | code4 | code5
row1    A       B       C
row2    B       A       D        E
row3   F       C
```

How can I group this table with count of value in codeX column
So

```
A: 2
   B: 2
   C: 2
   D: 1
   E: 1
   F: 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT productCode, count(*) AS count
FROM
(
    SELECT Code1 AS productCode FROM table
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Code2 FROM table
     UNION ALL
    SELECT Code3 FROM table
     UNION ALL
    SELECT Code4 FROM table
     UNION ALL
    SELECT Code5 FROM table

) AS codes
GROUP BY productCode
ORDER BY count DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want a list of the columns where something appears.  You can unpivot the table an use `group_concat`:

```
select code, count(*) as cnt, group_concat(which)
from (select code1 as code, 'code1' as which from table union all
      select code2, 'code2' as which from table union all
      select code3, 'code3' as which from table union all
      select code4, 'code4' as which from table
     ) c
where code is not null
group by code;
```

I used the full column names instead of `#1` -- it seems more useful.  But you can put in `#1` etc for `which`.

Comment: Well I wanna group with the value inside codeX, so not only for something. I want to have result for all values in codeX

Comment: actually, I only need count of appearance, any ideas?

Comment: @tugce . . . Just use `count(*)`.